# Windows 7 use some credential mapping?

Tags: windows-7, network-share, credentials

At the office we have a Windows 7 which was configured by a bad admin : he mapped the shares with an administrator user.
This Windows 7 is in a domain, and the admin user is named `admin`. So this Windows 7 accessed the servers with full rights.

On the Windows 7 I disconnected the drives, rebooted and reconnected them. Everything was running fine.
Later, I disabled the user `admin` on Active Directory to be sure nobody else used it.
And tadaaa... the former Windows 7 can no longer access the server.
Ok, I re-disconnect the shares, reboot and it is now impossible to reconnect them. I tested with `net use` but I get an error too.
If I enable `admin` account this is ok. So I guess the Windows 7 use some credential mapping. It memorize something, but where ?

Comment: What are the shareand file security settings on the shares you are trying to use? Start there and add a security group if needed. Be sure to check the shre and file permissions. Also check the security logs on the server as that will provide additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. look in Dredential Manager in Control Panel on the Windows 7 computer and delete the credentials if you find them there.
2. Run net use from a command prompt and make sure the mapped drives are no longer connected.
3. What error do you get when you try to reconnect the mapped drives?

Comment: in this case DREDential manager makes sense!

Comment: Nice, this was an entry into Credential Manager. I never ever used that, so I had no clue. Thanks !

Comment: Glad to help...